# We need to uniquely identify multiple lightning components on same page( using lightning app builder)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-button

We need to uniquely identify multiple lightning components on same page(added using lightning app builder) and we need to save respected responses and use them later. For this purpose we need a unique ID for every component that we add on the page, ID that is not changed later. For this we tried two solutions given below :

1. GlobalId  : If we try to use Global id using getGlobalId() method then there is a problem that GlobalId is not static and  global id not guaranteed to be same beyond the lifetime of the
   component. Link for this reference is given below : 
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm
2. Design Resources : We can get dynamic picklist values in design resources using datasource, It works perfectly to get any dynamic value. So we are trying to generate a random number with combination of some string values, But if we do so then in case of random number we are getting error  *Invalid Value[myuniqueKey]*. Even if we just make it time dependent using gettime which will return timestamp then we get same error while saving the page. The code is given below :

Code:

```
String componentKey  = String.valueOf(System.now().getTime()) ; 
VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows timeframeRows = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows(); 
VisualEditor.DataRow row1 = new VisualEditor.DataRow(componentKey, componentKey ); 
timeframeRows.addRow(row1);

return timeframeRows;
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem *might* be that the blank "Unique Id" field does not match the picklist value. Try using:

```
VisualEditor.DataRow row1 = new VisualEditor.DataRow(
        componentKey,
        componentKey,
        true
        );
```

that pre-selects the row.